# How to get products which has less than 1 image in Shopify Graphql API

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

How to get a list of products that have less than 1 image using Shopify Graphql API

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

As you can see from the documentation here: https://shopify.dev/api/admin-graphql/2022-01/queries/products

The possible query parameters are

- barcode
- created_at
- delivery_profile_id
- error_feedback
- gift_card
- has_only_default_variant
- id
- inventory_total
- is_price_reduced
- out_of_stock_somewhere
- price product_type
- publishable_status
- published_status
- sku
- status
- tag
- tag_not
- title
- updated_at
- vendor

---

So the only option is to retrieve only the first picture and filter yourself when the node product contains an empty array under images.

```
{
    products(first:10){
        edges{
            node{
                id
                images(first:1){
                    edges{
                        node{ url }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In python would be

```py
result = []
for product in products["edges"]:
   if len(product["node"]["images"]["edges"]) == 0:
      result.append(product["node"]["id"])
```

An alternative way would be to register on the webhook product/update and check

- if there are no product images you tag the product as "no_pictures"
- otherwise you remove the "no_pictures" tag

This way you can query by tag like this, for example

```
{
  products(first: 10, query: "tag:no_pictures") {
    edges {
      node {
        id
      }
    }
  }
}
```